# How to fix text which becomes invisible when viewing from a mobile device

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have created a basic WordPress button to link an external site in my pages. This works fine, but when viewing from a mobile device, the white text within the button disappears and the button changes from square to round:

http://www.passionatacollection.com/accommodation/hh-luxury-condo-2bedroom/

I have checked the class properties for wp-block-button & wp-block-button__link to see why this should change.

```html
<div class="wp-block-button aligncenter"><a class="wp-block-button__link" href="https://www.bettervacations.co/properties/5d0a543c7f3381002c0f77ae">BOOK NOW</a></div>
```

I need to add code to custom CSS to override this from hiding the text from mobile devices.

Comment: Did the below answer work for you?

Comment: Yes- it has resolved my issue. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put the below on the a tag, this will work for you:

```
<a style="color: #FFFFFF; border-radius: 0" class="wp-block-button__link" href="https://www.bettervacations.co/properties/5d0a543c7f3381002c0f77ae">BOOK NOW</a>
```

It looks like there's some Wordpress CSS being applied for smaller devices (including medium), you can either inline like the above or create a class and use !important to ensure it listens to your class rather than the WP one.